# How can I move unallocated space to a different disk? (Windows)

Tags: windows, storage

So I'm running out of space in my C: disk(in the picture below Disk 0) and I want to move some space from Disk 1 to Disk 0, how can I do that?[This is a picture of my disk management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5EQF.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can't move partition to another disk.

But you can make a folder on one disk, which is a mount point to a partition on another disk.

Honestly I wouldn't do that, I would have moved some files instead.